# Why is jquery function running twice, for image file upload and preview?

Tags: jquery, css, image, file-upload, dynamically-generated

would really appreciate some insight on the below image preview I am trying to achieve..
The entire div 'DIV_IMAGE_Upload_and_PREVIEW' is dynamically generated inside the 'CONTAINER' div, so am using the on('change'... ) type function.
Background: Am trying to generate an image preview in the element id IMG_PREVIEW.

Q1. Why is the jQuery on Change function triggering twice? ; while testing and running, i see the alerts "position A" and "image PASS" alerted twice. Why are these triggering twice? Its not creating a problem, but i would like to know.

Q2. Also, whats the best way to Display and Hide the IMG_PREVIEW element? If I use attr('visibility','visible'/'hidden' it still shows the footprint of the IMG_PREVIEW element (it has CSS height and width). is it advisable to use $('# ')css('display','flex'/'block') and $('# ')css('display','none') to show hide elements? Would really appreciate all help.

Also, winter is coming. Please be safe during this coronavirus period, and keep your pets indoors.

CSS

```
#IMG_PREVIEW
{   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: none;  
    width: 300px;  
    height: auto;  
    object-fit: contain;    align: top; }
#INPUT_FILE_PRIMARY   /* this is to format the file input */
{   order: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;    top: 0px;   bottom: 0px;
    width: 0.1px;   height: 0.1px; 
    opacity: 0.5;       }
```

HTML

```
<DIV id="CONTAINER">
<DIV id="DIV_IMAGE_Upload_and_PREVIEW"> 
    <FORM method='post' action='PHP/FILE_UPLOAD_CHECK.PHP' id="FORM_img_upload" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <INPUT type='file' name='filename_' size='10' id="INPUT_IMG_PRIMARY"></INPUT>
        <LABEL for="INPUT_FILE_PRIMARY" id="LBL_for_PRIMARY" class="form_inputs">Image</LABEL>
        <LABEL for="INPUT_FILE_PRIMARY" id="LBL_sml_for_PRIMARY" class="form_inputs">...</LABEL>                                
    </FORM>                                                                             
    <DIV id="DIV_error"></DIV>  
    <img id="IMG_PREVIEW"></img>    
</DIV>  
</DIV>
```

jQuery

```
$('#CONTAINER').on('change','#INPUT_IMG_PRIMARY', function(e){
                $("#DIV_error").html("");                           
                $("#IMG_PREVIEW").attr('src',"");                   
                
                $("#LBL_sml_for_PRIMARY").html(this.files[0].name);                 
                var ERS = 0;    
                var FIL_1 = e.target.files[0];              
                
                if(FIL_1.length===0)
                {   ERS++;  
                    $("#DIV_error").html("No file selected");                   
                }else if(!((FIL_1.type=='image/jpeg' ) || (FIL_1.type=='image/jpg') || (FIL_1.type=='image/png') || (FIL_1.type=='image/bmp')))
                        {   ERS++;                              
                            $("#DIV_error").html("Not Image File extn");                                    
                        }else if(FIL_1.size > (6*1024*1024)) //> 4MB
                            {   ERS++;                                  
                                $("#DIV_error").html("File > 6mb");
                            }       
                if(ERS>0)
                {   $("#IMG_PREVIEW").css('display', 'none');
                }
                
                alert('position A');
                
                if(ERS == 0)
                {   var FReader = new FileReader();
                    alert('image PASS');
                    FReader.onload = function()
                    {   $("#IMG_PREVIEW").css('display','block');                       
                        $("#IMG_PREVIEW").attr('src',FReader.result);                                       
                        $("#IMG_PREVIEW").css('margin-top','5px');                      
                    };          
                    FReader.readAsDataURL(FIL_1);           
                }                   
        });
```

Comment: Most common cause is you are loading the same code twice. What happens when you do `$('#CONTAINER').off('change').on('change....`? If the alert only appears once it suggests you have called the same code twice. Perhaps by using `load()` to insert a whole page with same scripts

Comment: @charlietfl .. mate you were right!! I had the jQuery script file included twice in the main HTML!!! Says you are an experienced programmer!! Thank you ma mayn!